# Send "on hold" email on custom order status change in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I've created a custom status in Woocommerce Order Page. It seems work.
So I was trying to send the same email of On Hold status, when my custom status is selected like this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_actions', 'filter_woocommerce_email_actions' );
function filter_woocommerce_email_actions( $actions ){
    $actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_wc-attesa-pagamento';
    return $actions;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_wc-attesa-pagamento', 'enable_processing_to_on_hold_notification', 10, 2 );
function enable_processing_to_on_hold_notification( $order_id, $order ){
    // Getting all WC_emails array objects
    $mailer = WC()->mailer()->get_emails();

    // Send the "On Hold" notification
    $mailer['WC_Email_Customer_On_Hold_Order']->trigger( $order_id );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_wc-attesa-pagamento', array( WC(), 'send_transactional_email' ), 10, 1 );
```

But nothing happen!
Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your code, you need to replace this line:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_wc-attesa-pagamento', 'enable_processing_to_on_hold_notification', 10, 2 );
```

with this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_attesa-pagamento', 'enable_processing_to_on_hold_notification', 10, 2 );
```

and it should works.